# HTTP Multipart data to object/array tree

Tags: c#, php, http, forms, multipart

Is there any library, preferably a simple one and in C#, that is capable of parsing the multipart data of a POST HTTP request and turn it into a tree made of objects and/or array nodes and primitive value leaves ?

In other words, let the following HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="whatever" method="POST">

            <input type="checkbox" name="boolean" checked="checked" />
            <input type="number" name="integer" value="123" />
            <input type="text" name="string" value="Hello world !" />

            <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" checked="chcked" />
            <input type="number" name="array[]" value="123" />
            <input type="text" name="array[]" value="Hello world !" />

            <input type="checkbox" name="object[boolean]" checked="checked" />
            <input type="number" name="object[integer]" value="123" />
            <input type="text" name="object[string]" value="Hello world !" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which would generate the following form data, which I will represent as JSON in order to make my point :

```
{
    "boolean"=true,
    "integer"=123,
    "string"="Hellow world !",
    "array[0]"=true,
    "array[1]"=123,
    "array[2]"="Hello world",
    "object[boolean]"=true,
    "object[integer]"=123,
    "object[string]"="Hello world"
}
```

The library would "unflatten" the data, i.e turn it from a map with no depth into a tree, which I will represent as JSON too :

```
{
    "boolean": true,
    "integer": 123,
    "string": "Hello world !",
    "array": [
        true,
        123,
        "Hello world !"
    ],
    "object": [
        "boolean": true,
        "integer": 123,
        "string": "Hello world !"
    ]
}
```

This is similar to what PHP does when it initializes $_POST.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Care to have the mimimum decency of commenting as to why this question that seems perfectly legitimate to me should be closed ?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: So where would you suggest I ask this question ?